# Printing an HTML page header is different when saved in a var?

Tags: html, perl

this works fine:

```
print $cgi->header({-type => "text/html", -expires => "now"}),
$cgi->start_html({-title => "TEST PAGE",
      -style => [{-type => "text/css", -src =>"one.css"},
                 {-type => "text/css", -src =>"calendar.css"}],
      -script => [
     {-type => "text/javascript", -src => "main.js"},
                 ]}),
  $cgi->start_form({-name => "test", -autocomplete => "off"});
```

but if instead I try:

```
my $html= $cgi->header({-type => "text/html", -expires => "now"}),
$cgi->start_html({-title => "TEST PAGE",
      -style => [{-type => "text/css", -src =>"one.css"},
                 {-type => "text/css", -src =>"calendar.css"}],
      -script => [
     {-type => "text/javascript", -src => "main.js"},
                 ]}),
  $cgi->start_form({-name => "test", -autocomplete => "off"});
print $html;
```

The HTML is then displayed on the page instead of rendered? Why would saving all the HTML in a var then printing that var produce a different result than printing directly? It's difficult to capture what's different because of the subtle differences like capturing a \n\n ..

Do I have to sprint that header into the var or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Perl's concatenation operator is `.`, not `,`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why would saving all the HTML in a var then printing that var produce a different result than printing directly?

For the same reason that

```
print 'foo', 'bar'; # outputs foobar
```

is different than

```
my $foo = 'foo', 'bar';
print $foo; # outputs foo
```

[`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) takes a list and outputs all the elements separated by `$,` (`undef` by default).

The [comma operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) in scalar context evaluates its left operand, throws away the result, evaluates its right operand, and returns that value. So `my $foo = 'foo', 'bar'` assigns the string `foo` to `$foo` and returns the string `bar`.

---

Also note that the [HTML generation functions in CGI.pm are deprecated](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used):

> **HTML Generation functions should no longer be used**
>
> All HTML generation functions within CGI.pm are no longer being maintained. Any issues, bugs, or patches will be rejected unless they relate to fundamentally broken page rendering.
>
> The rationale for this is that the HTML generation functions of CGI.pm are an obfuscation at best and a maintenance nightmare at worst. You should be using a template engine for better separation of concerns. See CGI::Alternatives for an example of using CGI.pm with the Template::Toolkit module.
>
> These functions, and perldoc for them, are considered deprecated, they are no longer being maintained and no fixes or features for them will be accepted.

Comment: Your example will print `foo`. You would need parentheses to print `bar`: `my $foo = ('foo', 'bar');`

Comment: DOH! Thanks guys. I don't ever print lists- this was some code I got frmo another author. I'll concat everything and we should be good!

Comment: @MattJacob Damn precedence. Thanks, fixed.